# Making a row to have hover effect in Bootstrap 4 without using a table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, mousehover

I was wondering if there was a way to make a row here hover?  I want to point out I am not using a table to create this, but using the grid system in Bootstrap 4. Is it even possible?  Everything I have researched points to that you need to create a table in order for this to happen.

```html
 <div class="row">
        <div class="report-card-i report-card-i-height">
            <h3 class="m-l-35 p-t-25 p-b-10">Compliance</h3>
            <div class="fa-orange m-t-10 m-b-15 m-l-80">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15 text-center" style="font-weight: bold">Adjustment</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>21,922</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$304,012.23</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right text-center" style="font-weight: bold"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just edited the question.  I basically want to entire row highlighted when the mouse cursor hovers over Adjustment and any of the text in that particular row.

Comment: So `.row:hover > *` doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
.mydiv div:hover{background-color:gray;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="report-card-i report-card-i-height">
            <h3 class="m-l-35 p-t-25 p-b-10">Compliance</h3>
            <div class="fa-orange m-t-10 m-b-15 m-l-80">
                <div class="row mydiv">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-star m-r-15 text-center" style="font-weight: bold">Adjustment</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>21,922</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$304,012.23</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                        <p>$0.00</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right text-center" style="font-weight: bold"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In my code, I needed to make this change to highlight the entire row:      `.mydiv:hover{background-color:gray;}`

Answer (score 3):

I would change

```
<div class="fa-orange m-t-10 m-b-15 m-l-80">
    <div class="row">
```

to

```
<div class="fa-orange m-t-10 m-b-15 m-l-80">
    <div class="row highlight">
```

so that the following css selector only targets rows with the `.highlight` class:

```
.row.highlight:hover > * {
    background-color: #123456;
}
```